# For Loop Step -1

Tags: vb.net, loops

I want to know why this loop doesn't show anything in VB.NET.

I think this code will create an infinite loop. But it doesn't show anything.

```
Dim i as Integer
For i = 1 to 3 Step - 1
    MessageBox.Show(i)
Next
```

Is that loop different with this code (in java/c#) ?

```
for(int i = 1;i <= 3;i--)
{
  // print i
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5z06z1kb.aspx
With a negative step size the loop only executes if counter >= end. So in this case with i = 1, that is less than the ending value so the loop doesn't execute at all.

Comment: Thanks, that link give me the explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't show anything because you are running the counter backwards without reversing the start and end conditions.

Think of the loop like this:

```
Dim counter As Int32 = 1
Do
  If counter <= 1 Then
    Exit Do
  End If
  Console.WriteLine("The counter is at " & counter)
  counter +=1
Loop
```

Obviously this won't work properly.
You need to reverse the start and end conditions:

```
For counter = 3 To 1 Step -1
  Console.WriteLine("counter: " & counter)
Next
```

Comment: Yes, if i reverse start and end condition it will work. But i curious why that loop doesn't generate an infinite loop?

Answer (score 0):

```
For i = 1 to 3 Step - 1
```

It won't create an infinite loop. The loop will simply be skipped, because you can't get from 1 to 3 with a step value of -1.

> Is that loop different with this code (in java/c#) ?

This loop will also end immediately, because the initial value (`i = 1`) meets the exit condition (`i <= 3`).

Comment: `This loop will also end immediately,`, you mean that second loop doesn't print anything?

Comment: Correct. The loop is skipped over because its exit condition is met before it even iterates once.