# VB.NET: Part of code not executing at all

Tags: vb.net, for-loop

I have code in VB.NET that includes two nested For statements. E.g.

```
For i = 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
 MsgBox("First For statement")
 For x = 5 to 1
  MsgBox("Second For statement")
 Next
Next
```

Now the first For statement executes fine but the second one doesn't. How come? Shouldn't the code execute line by line?

Comment: The default is for a `For` statement to **increase** the loop variable. If you really want to decrease from 5 to 1, you need `For x = 5 To 1 Step -1`

Comment: Related: [For Loop Step -1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22678063/1115360).

Comment: Your answer worked for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For loop syntaxe in Vb.net :

```
For counter [ As datatype ] = start To end [ Step step ]
[ statements ]
[ Continue For ]
[ statements ]
[ Exit For ]
[ statements ]
Next [ counter ]
```

You missed step in your code

```
For x = 5 to 1 step -1
   MsgBox("Second For statement")
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

> Now the first For statement executes fine but the second one doesn't.
>   How come?

See [For...Next Statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/for-next-statement):

> When a For...Next loop starts, Visual Basic evaluates start, end, and
>   step. Visual Basic evaluates these values only at this time and then
>   assigns start to counter. Before the statement block runs, Visual
>   Basic compares counter to end. If counter is already larger than the
>   end value (or smaller if step is negative), the For loop ends and
>   control passes to the statement that follows the Next statement.
>   Otherwise, the statement block runs.

Since 5 is already greater than 1, the inner loop never executes.

The documentation also states that:

> The default value of step is 1.

So if you want the loop to **decrement** (count backwards), you need to specify a **negative** Step value.  Assuming you want it to decrement by 1 (one) each time, you'd change your code to:

```
For i = 0 to ListBox1.Items.Count - 1
    MsgBox("First For statement")
    For x = 5 to 1 Step -1
        MsgBox("Second For statement")
    Next
Next
```